# CSS свойство z-index не работает

Tags: css

Я задал родителю значение свойства positon: static; для дочернего допустим menu1 и logo поставил absolute. и разные z-index. и все равно они как бы находятся на одной плоскости, а не как обещано с z-index в разных.

Comment: Как они могу быть на одной плоскости если у них разные z-index? Тем более что их position: absolute вынесло из нормального потока.

http://jsfiddle.net/dCtnX/

Comment: не помогает(

Comment: все)))я оказывается все правильно сделал...просто когда два класса вместе указывал ошибку допустил)спасибо)

Comment: Какого результата Вы хотите добиться?

Comment: нет я результата добился)))спасибо))за оказанную помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот очень годная [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/166435/) про z-index-ы